# Using the same numbering in two different {chapter*}

Tags: chapters, counters

I'm currently writting my thesis and I have to record two introductions (environment \chapter*) : one in French and one in English. Since the informations and equations are exactly the same, I would like to use the same numerotation for both chapter. But it seems like latex considers that the two environments chapter* belong to the same chapter.

Do you have any idea to fix my problem?
This is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,french,reqno]{amsbook}    
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage[english]{}  
\usepackage{hyperref}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter*{French}  
\section{Section 1}  
\begin{equation}\label{eq1_FR}  
x=y  
\end{equation}  
La première équation \eqref{eq1_FR}.  

\chapter*{English}  
\stepcounter{chapter}  
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}  
\section{Section 1}  
\begin{equation}  
\label{eq1_EN}  
x=y  
\end{equation}  
I cite the first equation \eqref{eq1_EN} of the chapter "English", but the hyperref sends me to the equations \eqref{eq1_FR}, even if there are well labeled.  

\chapter{First chapter}  

\begin{equation}  
\label{chap1}  
x=y  
\end{equation}  

There is no problem for this equation \eqref{chap1}.  
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe `\setcounter{equation}{0}` after the second `\chapter*`?

Comment: One solution could be to reset the counter for equations `\setcounter{equation}{0}`. But I don't know if this is a good solution.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but: If, after `\begin{chapter*}`, you insert `\stepcounter{chapter}`, then all the counters that should be reset at a chapter start should be reset. Follow it by `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}` in order not to mess up chapter numbering. Of course, if `\theequation`, `\thesection` and so on contain a reference to the chapter number, you have a bigger problem. But I trust you realize that, and know what to do if so. (If this works, let me know in a comment, and I'll convert it to an answer.)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help! All of these solutions works fine, and it gives the right numerotation. However, the hyperlink of an equation in the second introduction (\eqref{intro2:eq1}) leads me to the right equation but in the first introduction (\label{intro1:eq1}). I have the same problem for the hyperlink of the sections, but not for the hyperlink of the figures. Yes, this lacks logic!

Comment: @Norah You have to use different labels in both sections, for example `\label{intro1:eq1:english}` and `\label{intro1:eq1:french}`

Comment: @samcarter I did use different labels..

Comment: @Norah Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Norah Please add it to your question

Comment: @samcarter. I just added it.

Answer (score 1):

From the example document, I assume that English is the main language.

In order to reset the counters related to `chapter`, the strategy is to issue `\stepcounter{chapter}`, accompanied by `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}` to keep the number to zero.

For `hyperref` one can locally redefine `\theHchapter` so to give unique anchors in the French part.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,reqno]{amsbook}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        % not utf8x
\usepackage[french,english]{babel} % english is the main language
%\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}       % redundant with amsbook
%\usepackage{amsfonts}             % redundant with amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}               % redundant with amsbook

\usepackage{hyperref}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{FR\thechapter}

\chapter*{French}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1_FR}
x=y
\end{equation}
La première équation \eqref{eq1_FR}.

\end{otherlanguage}

\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}  
\stepcounter{chapter}

\chapter*{English}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1_EN}
x=y
\end{equation}
I cite the first equation \eqref{eq1_EN} of the chapter "English", 
but the hyperref sends me to the equations \eqref{eq1_FR}, 
even if there are well labeled.

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{equation}
\label{chap1}
x=y
\end{equation}

There is no problem for this equation \eqref{chap1}.

\end{document}
```

Note that `utf8x` has been unmaintained for several years and that, on the contrary, `utf8` is actively maintained and developed by the LaTeX team.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine. I also take into account your remark on utfx8 !